# Clicking a timestamp in youtube comments takes you to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make some js code that doesn't let the page take you back to the top when you click a timestamp in youtube's comment section.

```js
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function ch() {
    i = 0;
    k = 0;
    while (i >= 0) {

        var a = document.querySelector('a[class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string"]')
            if (a == null) {

                break;
            }
            var el = document.createElement("a");

        el.setAttribute("name", "click" + i);
        insertAfter(a, el);
        var cl = a.className;
        a.setAttribute('href', a + "#click" + i);
        a.setAttribute('class', cl + i);
        i++;
    }
    setTimeout(ch, 5000);
}

ch();
```

I new to coding so it's really simple. When I run the code using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/run-javascript/lmilalhkkdhfieeienjbiicclobibjao/related?hl=en) chrome extension the html of the page changes as intended but clicking a timestamp takes me to the top anyway. I don't know what to do and I'm starting to think that this action might be handled by the server making me unable to change it in any way. Thanks.

Comment: I think, you are totally right with your conclusion, that your code is supposed to be delivered by the yyoutube server in order to work for you and other. If you only use the chrome plugin with this code, it will only change the html page for the current session. Reloading the page will provide you the standard youtube behaviour again. :) Some additional information: [JavaScript — Dynamic client-side scripting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript)

Comment: you can also experiment with a kind of [proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826522/add-your-javascript-to-any-page-using-proxy-or-something-else) to add javascript or you can try to use [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)

Comment: @Rene thank you for your answer, I'll try using those then. Have a nice day :)